# Keep the form of a summation

Tags: summation

I have an input dialog box in which you must enter a formula. This formula consists of a summation of terms of x (x subscript i). I intend to keep the form of this expression but Mathematica converts this expression in a sum of terms. I mean, for example, if I input "Summation from i=1 to 10 of x_i", Mathematica converts this expression in "x_1+x_2+...+x_10" and I want to keep the original form.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
estadistico1 = 
 Input["Please input a statistic. For example " TraditionalForm[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(n\)]
\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(i\)]\)/n]]
```

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

[image: Summation]

Comment: Enter `Inactive[Sum]` rather than `Sum`

Comment: Thanks for your repose. But the problem is not that. When someone puts an input into the input dialog box like the one you can see in my example, I want the app keep the form of the expression and it does not convert the summation into a sum of terms of x. Suppose that instead of 10 term we have 1000. It is not operational that the app shows a sum of 1000 terms. Besides, I pretend to show later this expression (the expression that is input by the usuary of the app) but in a short form. In any case, thanks for your response.